# Como hacer una consulta usando AJAX desde un ComboBox

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un ComboBox que carga los *option* desde la base de datos.

Necesito que al momento de seleccionar algún dato cargue la consulta, dependiendo de la opción seleccionada, todo esto con AJAX.

Comment: ¿En que lenguaje de programación? Java no es JavaScript... Por otro lado, ¿podrías [edit] la pregunta mostrando qué intentaste hasta ahora? Facilita la tarea de alguien que quiera ayudarte mostrar el código y marcar en qué estás teniendo problemas. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: para realizar las llamadas ajax usas jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

Agrega una función ajax en el evento `onclick`. Le pasas, por ejemplo, el id del elemento que has seleccionado para poder hacer la consulta en la base de datos.

```
elemento.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    llamarAjax(event.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar `onchange`.

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">
```

Luego capturar el valor del `select` (ComboBox) y usar el *AJAX* en la función asignada al `onchange`.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias asociarte al evento change del combo y alli realizar la llamada ajax

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        $("#comboId").change(function(){

            var seleccion = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "url",
                data: seleccion,
                datatype: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

En este caso hago uso de jquery para controlar el evento y ademas invocar al servidor mediante ajax

Comment: reemplaza esto:  $('#result').html(data); por esto  $('#result').html('').html(data); //Así evitas agregar una larga lista de los datos que devuelva el post.