# Evitar el refresh completo de la pagina al mandar funcion get en jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola tengo dos funciones en jQuery que al hacer click en el botón `btn_enviar` envían por AJAX los datos a la base de datos.

Además tengo un `$.get` que escribe los datos en controles de HTML.

Quisiera poder enviar los datos sin que haga el refresh de la página completa, y sólo actualice los controladores.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $.get("<?php echo base_url('obteneract') ?>","",function(data){

        console.log(data);
        var json1=JSON.parse(data);
        var actividad="";

        for(post in json1){
            actividad+="<li>"+json1[post].Nombre+"</li>";
            $("#actividades").html(actividad);
        }
    });

});

$("#btn_enviar").click(function(){

    var data=$("#formulariocurso :input").serializeArray();
    $.post($("#formulariocurso").attr("action"),data, function(info){

    });
});
```

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Descripcion actividad" id="Actividad" name="Actividad" required>
<button class="button expanded"  id="btn_enviar"> Registrar Curso </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Creo que necesitas leer un poco sobre Ajax y su utilidad para comunicaciones asíncronas entre cliente y servidor, sin necesidad de recarga de la página.

Considero que [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24583/enviar-post-a-php-por-medio-de-ajax/24588#24588) hay un buen ejemplo. Y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax/21755#21755) un poco más conceptual.

Otras preguntas relacionadas: [Cómo hacer una consulta usando ajax desde un combobox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28219/como-hacer-una-consulta-usando-ajax-desde-un-combobox/28323#28323) y [ejecutar función php en el on click de un botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63227/ejecutar-funcion-php-en-el-onclick-de-un-boton/63230#63230).

Comment: bro, de los enlaces que has puesto, extrae los ejemplos para que le aumentes la calidad a tu pregunta, caso contrario puede que te la cierren por que dar enlaces solamente no está considerado como buena respuesta. Saludos :D